# Getting output of duplicates and not the same as another column

Tags: sqlite, duplicates

Example database:

```
column1 | column2
--------+---------
1       |  1
2       |  1
3       |  3
4       |  3
5       |  5
6       |  7
7       |  3
```

I would like to get an output of

```
2 | 1
4 | 3
7 | 3
```

This is the query I use:

```
SELECT 
    column2, COUNT(*) c 
FROM 
    table 
GROUP BY 
    column2 
HAVING 
    c > 1
```

which returns:

```
1 | 2
3 | 3
```

I would like to take it a step further:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE (column1 != column2 AND having count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: Can you explain, in english, not psuedo-sql, how you get your desired output from that example table and why those rows and not others?

Comment: On the face of it, the sql to get the output from the example db would simply be `SELECT column1, column2 from table WHERE column2 < column1`

Comment: I have 2 columns, ideally the values should be the same between the 2, but some are not.. there should be no duplicates in column 2. So I wanted to get an output of rows where column 2 has a duplicate and it does not match column 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first SQL

```
SELECT column2, COUNT(*) c 
FROM table 
GROUP BY column2 
HAVING c > 1
```

returns a nice list of the column2 values you want. You will need a self-JOIN and get the column1's that go with. That will require using table aliases. You could try it this way

```
SELECT T1.column1, T1.column2 
from table T1
JOIN (SELECT column2, count(*) c
      FROM table
      GROUP BY column2
      HAVING c > 1) T2 ON T2.column2 = T1.column2
WHERE T1.column1 <> T2.column2
```

---

---

[Author's note] This is not the answer as originally written. [The stack help re: editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) says:

> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than
>   you found it. Common reasons for edits include:
>
> - To fix grammar and spelling mistakes
> - To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)
> - To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place
> - To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages
> - To add related resources or hyperlinks

The edit does not meet any of the criteria. However, on the same page it says:

> If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being
>   collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the
>   site for you.

So be it.